# Finding a function from its Maclaurin series

Tags: taylor-expansion

I recently came across the following:

$\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+\frac{3}{4!}+\frac{4}{5!}+...=1$

The factorials in the denominators reminded me of a Taylor Series. In particular, I found that it fit the Maclaurin series, evaluated at 1:

$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2+\frac{f^{(3)}(0)}{3!}x^3+\frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!}x^4+...$

But that it would only do so, given the following:

1. $f(1)=1$
2. $f(0)=0$
3. $f'(0)=0$
4. $f''(0)=1$
5. $f^{(3)}(0)=2$
6. $f^{(4)}(0)=3$

etc...

Is there a method for finding out what function, if one even exists, would yield this Maclaurin series? It would have to be a function for which each subsequent differentiation (evaluated at 0) results in only an incremental factor. I am having trouble imagining how that would be possible, but am curious to see if there's a way to find out.

Comment: If there is such an $f$ then for example $f(x)+c\cdot \exp(-1/x^2)$ (where I define $\exp(-1/x^2)$ as $0$ at $x=0$) also has the same Maclaurin series. For your particular problem: what happens if you add $e=1+1/1!+1/2!+\ldots$ to your original series?

Comment: @Gary: very nice hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method that can be used for this kind of problem is to use the information in the Taylor series to generate a differential equation. Thanks to Zwim in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2261972/233347) for introducing me to this method.

### Finding the Maclaurin series

From the generic Maclaurin series formula, we have
$$f(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n.$$

Next, we need to find an expression for those derivative terms.

$$
\begin{align}
f(0)&=0 \\
f'(0)&=0\\
f''(0)&=1\\
f'''(0)&=2\\
f^{(4)}(0)&=3\\
...\\
f^{(n)}(0)&=n-1\end{align}$$

Our full formula for $f(x)$, after plugging in the derivatives (note that our sum starts at $n=1$ because the constant term is zero):
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{n!}x^n$$

### Finding the differential equation:

Begin by taking the derivative of $f$:

$$
f'(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n-1}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}
$$

Reindexing:

$$
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n!}x^{n}
\end {align}
$$

Now, expressing $f$ in terms of $f'$:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) & =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{n!}x^n \\
&=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n!}x^n\right)-\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}x^n\right) \\
&=f'(x)-e^x+1
\end{align}
$$

(Note that the $e^x-1$ in the expression comes from starting the sum at $n=1$ instead of $n=0$ -- the constant term of the exponential Taylor series is missing.) We now have a first-order linear inhomogenous differential equation for $f$.

$$
f-\frac{df}{dx}=-e^x+1
$$

### Solving and verifying:

This can be solved by a computer algebra program, by guessing and checking, or by the method of undetermined coefficients (which I was going to use explicitly in this answer, but I don't remember it well enough to explain it).

The answer we get is

$$f(x)=ce^x+xe^x+1.$$

Solving for our initial condition $f(0)=0$:

$$
\begin{align}
0 &= f(0)\\
0 &= ce^0+0*e^0+1\\
0 &= c + 1\\
c &= -1
\end{align}
$$

Giving us a complete answer of

$$f(x)=-e^x + xe^x + 1.$$

Finally, repeated differentiation gives us the following sequence, verifying that this is indeed a solution to the original question and clarifying exactly why differentiation increments the function value by one.

$$\begin{alignat*}{2}
f(x)    &= -e^x+  xe^x+1, &f(0)    = 0 \\
f'(x)   &=        xe^x,   &f'(0)   =0\\
f''(x)  &=  e^x + xe^x,     &f''(0)  =1\\
f'''(x) &= 2e^x + xe^x,     &f'''(0) =2\\
f''''(x) &= 3e^x + xe^x,     &f'''(0) =3\\
... &...
\end{alignat*}$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How did you arrive at your first f(x)? I see similarities to the motivating series as well as the Maclaurin series, but it doesn't quite match either. The original series doesn't involve x and the Maclaurin series involves derivatives that I don't see reflected in your f(x). I understand your logic from there, however.

Comment: @GolanTrevize I've edited my answer to make that part more explicit

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your sum is of the form
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n-1}{n!}$$
and we know that
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
So that
$$\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}$$
and now differentiating both sides leads to
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)=\frac{xe^x-e^x+1}{x^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)x^{n-1}}{n!}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)x^{n-1}}{n!},$$
where the equality in the last step is due to the $n=1$ term being $0$. Evaluating this in $x=1$ gives
$$1=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)}{n!}$$
as hoped

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @b00nheT but without differentiation,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{n!} = \sum_{n\ge 2}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac{1}{n!} = \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n!}-\sum_{n \ge 2}\frac{1}{n!} = (e-1)-(e-1-1)=1.
$$

This is sufficient to prove the equality.

Comment: Nice: much simpler indeed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I am not looking to prove the equality, only to find out what f(x) is. The equality was only there to motivate the creation of the Maclaurin series.